# не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::string" в "LPTSTR"

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь сделать,чтобы функция **isProcessRun** воспринимала корректно текст из массива.

```
   bool isProcessRun(LPTSTR processName)
    {
        HANDLE hSnap = NULL;
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
        hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (hSnap!=NULL)
        {
            if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32))
            {
                if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, processName) == 0)
                    return TRUE;
                while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32))
                    if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, processName) == 0)
                        return TRUE;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    int main() 
    {   
        string watching_programs[] = { "test1.exe","test2.exe"};
        for (string programs : watching_programs)
        {
    
            if (isProcessRun(programs))
            {
            cout << "found soft " + programs;
            }
        else
            {
            cout << "soft not found!";
            }
        }
        cin.get();
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: у класса `string` есть метод `c_str()`, который возвращает строку в виде массива символов (в общем си строку)

Comment: Вот тут думаю есть ответ на ваш вопрос: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279753/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lptstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isProcessRun(programs.c_str())
```

или

```
isProcessRun(programs.data())
```

Если с `.data()` у вас не работает... Ну, что-то типа

```
char buf[1000];
strcpy(buf,programs.c_str());
isProcessRun(buf);
```

Comment: Я уже ранее пробовал такой способ,на выходе получаю ошибку: `аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPTSTR"`

Comment: С `data()`? Не может быть... Тогда сделайте копию, см. ответ.

Comment: Кстати формально говоря там строка из TCHAR т.е. это решение сработает только для TCHAR = char варианта. Для общего случая надо использовать Utf8->Utf16 функции преобразования.

Comment: @Arty Кроме как в вашем комментарии, нигде `TCHAR` на этой странице не нашел...

Comment: @Mikhailo Да, т.к. isProcessRun() принимает строку типа LPTSTR, а этот тип это просто указатель `TCHAR *`. Если вы не в курсе, то TCHAR это такой тип, специально придуманный Microsoft. Каждое приложение в вижуал студии бывает либо ASCII типа либо UNICODE, так вот когда у приложения задан макрос UNICODE то после включения Windows.h этот TCHAR равен `wchar_t`, если юникод не задан то он равен `char`.Все WinApi функции работающие со строками, например CreateFile имеют два варианта CreateFileA и CreateFileW, CreateFile это макрос, на вход принимает TCHAR,он уже выбирает сам CreateFileA/CreateFileW

Comment: Т.е. суть в том что макйрософт есть понятие T-строки, это `char*` в не-юникодных приложениях и `wchar_t*` в униюкодных. Получается если использовать скажем CreateFile вызов, то в юникодных он потребует на вход wchar_t* а в аски приложениях потребует char*. Вообщем не будет компилироваться в юникодных приложениях если в CreateFile подать char*.

Comment: OP использовал у себя тоже T-функцию `lstrcmp`, она в уникодных приложениях просто не скомпилируется если ей подать char*. Конечно в данном случае проще использова A-функцию т.е. `lstrcmpA` но формально при включении юникода просто ваш код не скомпилируется.